# How do i correctly Place an <aside> tag?

Tags: html, css, web

So here is my problem. My site runs on responsive design, Everything till now is working fine. But the main problem is the ASIDE content i should have. Here is a perfect example of how my site is literally sectioned:

[image]

My question is, how can i correctly position that aside section like in this diagram so it can also render responsive BUT on the bottom of the entire content (article/section) so when it renders on iPhone, the aside is right in the bottom of the main content with about 2% margin separating the Two?

Also in desktop is should render like in the diagram.

I can attempt to position the Aside section using a DIV by nesting the aside in this div and then a

```
      float: right;
```

which would move it to the right but i feel that it is a wrong way to do it since on previous examples i see people use float: left and yet get the same result on the right side.

So what would be my best way of doing this ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want it to look like on screen on desktop, but on iphona aside should be under article? If so do you use bootstrap or need solution with pure css?

Comment: Well, you are right, its how i basically want it, Diagram in desktop and the same aside in the bottom of the main content on mobile. i would prefer on pure css since i have no clue whats bootstrap is yet or how to use it.

Comment: Use `float:left` on both "article" and "aside" and set min-width when to manage responsive action. Don't forget to clear your floats to not mess up the footer.

Answer (score 0):

css for small devices:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { // devices recognized as phones - under 768px
 article{width: 100%;}
 aside{width:100%}
}
```

Comment: This should work, since i also have other media queries that render on tablets but my main concern was iPhones. I will definetly try this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<header id="header"> header </header>
<nav id="nav"> navigation </nav>
<article id="article"> article </article>
<aside id="aside"> aside </aside>
<footer id="footer"> footer </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { margin:0; padding:0;}
#wrapper { width:700px; max-width:100%; margin:0 auto;}
#article, #aside, #header, #nav, #footer { background:grey; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:20px 0;  color:#fff;}
#article, #aside{float:left;}
#article { width:72.91666666666667%; margin-right:1.041666666666667%;}
#aside { width:26.04166666666667%;}
#footer { clear:left;}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    #article, #aside{float:none; width:100%;}
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/576nQ/1/)