# CSS: Responsive design - how do I move floated elements to the bottom for specific orientation?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a very simple layout with one DIV and two ASIDEs, where the ASIDEs are floated to the left, and the content of the DIV (just long text) flows around the ASIDEs (BTW - the page is intentionally aligned right-to-left):

[image]

The problem is that this site is responsive, and when the screen goes into portrait mode, the ASIDEs must be placed below the DIV:

[image]

Now, if the ASIDEs are created first, that I can get the floating done correctly - but I can't move the ASIDEs after the DIV in portrait mode, because I don't know the height of the DIV.

If the ASIDEs are created after the DIV, I can easily get them to show up after the DIV in portrait mode, but I can't float them next to the DIV.

Is there any way to get what I want without simply having two copies of the ASIDEs, one before and one after the DIV?

The code is attached below, although JsFiddle doesn't render the asides as it should for some reason (even though the code is correct).

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 20px; 
  font-size: 13pt;
}

aside {
    padding: 20px; 
    float: left; 
    width: 200px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#red {
    background-color: red;
}

#blue {
    background-color: blue:
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<aside id="red">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</aside>
<aside id="blue">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</aside>
<div>
 The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
<br>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
<br>
Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
<br>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
<br>
1914 translation by H. Rackham
<br>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
<br>
Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
<br>
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
<br>
1914 translation by H. Rackham
<br>
"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
<br>
 The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s
<br>
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
<br>
Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
<br>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
<br>
1914 translation by H. Rackham
<br>
"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
<br>
Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC
<br>
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
<br>
1914 translation by H. Rackham
<br>
"On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cant do it directly using css only

but these are two suggested workaround to solve this issue:

1. to have additional two duplicated asides after the long text, then in portrait mode hide the first two aside and show the later two aside. and when in normal mode show the first two and hide the later two.

2.using JavaScript to cut the two asides and insert them after the long text in portrait mode.

Comment: Thanks Tawfiq. I don't really want to use Javascript since I'm trying to keep that down to a minimum - I guess I'll have to duplicate those asides...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can split your problem into two separate problems.

1. How to get left aside to go to the bottom of the content on smaller screens. (Think of the red+blue box as one)
2. Inside the aside element how to at first display elements on top of each other and on smaller screen split into two columns.

Here's a way where this system somewhat works. Might not be ideal but can get you started: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjhcufwg/)

For the first problem the first thing I found was this: 
[How do i correctly Place an <aside> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927767/how-do-i-correctly-place-an-aside-tag)

Just changed the `float: left;` part with `float: right`;

Second problem was easy, just use the same breakpoint to give both #red and #blue width of 50% and go from there.

For the first problem you could also probably check how bootstrap has implemented classes like `pull-xs-left` and `pull-xs-right` etc.

---

The main reason I wanted to make this post is that it's easier to search this as two separate problems. You can probably get more answers like this.

Comment: Hey Artur - thanks for the detailed reply. I thought about this, but the problem with fitting the asides into a single div (or any other element) and then floating the article and the asides-container, is that I'll be getting two distinct columns. I need the article to wrap around the asides, so that it takes up all available space - in other words, when the asides reach their end, I need the article to span to the edge of the screen. That's why I can't use two elements floated next to each other, and that is why this problem is a difficult one.

Answer (score 0):

try this style sheet

```
<style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            padding: 20px;
            font-size: 13pt;
        }

        aside {
            margin-right: 2em;
            height: 10em;
            width: 200px;

        }

        #red {
            float: left;
            height: background-color: red;
            margin-bottom: 4em;
        }

        #blue {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10em;
            background-color: blue: clear: left;
        }

    </style>
```

I think its more of a hack but i hope it helps your situation..

Take care and happy coding..